# Hide/show bottom navigation soft keys

Tags: android

I want hide bottom navigation soft keys only in one fragment and in others fragments again show those keys. Can someone provide me the code of hide/show keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19049898/1186689) of [damian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124160/damian)

> in build.prop
>
> ```
>  qemu.hw.mainkeys=0 (show on screen buttons)
>     or
>
>     qemu.hw.mainkeys=1 (disable on screen buttons)
> ```